# Update MongoDB $jsonSchema with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, jsonschema

Spring Data documentation [describes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.jsonSchema) how to create collection with given `$jsonSchema`, and how to perform a validation query.

Is there a way to update `$jsonSchema` for an existing collection? `MongoTemplate.createCollection()` for an existing one results in `MongoCommandException` with error code 48 (collection exists), schema is not being updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, looks like there is no ready-to-use method in Spring Data, but it is pretty simple to implement:

```java
<T> void updateSchema(MongoTemplate template, Class<T> entityClazz, MongoJsonSchema schema) {
    template.executeCommand(new Document(Map.of(
            "collMod", template.getCollectionName(entityClazz),
            "validator", schema.toDocument()
    )));
}
```

Also keep in mind that default `readWrite` role is not enough, user needs to have `collMod` privilege.

Comment: Using the Map to create Document can change the order of fields and will cause an error because mongo expects the fields for commands in a specific order i.e., collMod before validator. Instead do `new Document("collMod", template.getCollectionName(entityClazz)).append("validator", schema.toDocument())`